# Magento2: How to update/change Welcome/Subscription email?

Tags: magento2, email, template, subscription

Where I can change my welcome email or subscription email? And also I need to translate them to different languages. Maybe you can send tutorials how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to update the welcome email from the Magento admin panel:

**Steps:**

1. Goto Magento admin -> Marketing -> Communications -> Email Templates -> Add New Template
2. After redirecting to the new template page, just load the New Account. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

3. In the content section, you can update the content as per your requirement.
4. After creating the new template, goto Store -> Configuration - Customers - Customer Configuration -> Default Welcome Email

**Here is the configuration screenshot:**

[image]

After updating the new template in the customer configuration, just flush the Magento cache & test the email.

This is the easiest way to update the email template contents. and In the same way, you can update Subscription email content or other email templates.

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day!